# Выводится сообщение об ошибке при загрузке скрипта с помощью $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На странице с помощью метода:

```
function loadScript(scriptPath) {
$.getScript(scriptPath)
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        console.log( textStatus );
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
        console.log('Скрипт ' + scriptPath + ' не загрузился');
    });
}
```

В консоль выводятся сообщения об успешной загрузке скриптов и сообщения об ошибках в первой строке загруженного скрипта:
[image: Консоль Mozilla]

Что необходимо изменить в функции или добавить в загружаемые библиотеки, чтобы избавиться от этих сообщений? Или их можно игнорировать?

Консоль Google Chrome выдает ошибки:

[image: Ошибки в консоли Google Chrome]

126 строка - вызов $.getScript;
120 строка - вызов loadScript

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что эти ошибки связанны с загрузкой скриптов? У вас справа показывается название файла, номер строки и колонки где ошибка

Comment: Скрипты загружаются, потому что работают + 'success' - это сообщение об успешности загрузки

Comment: смущает наличие ошибки

Comment: Тогда приведите ошибку

Comment: Последние 4 строки в консоли

Comment: "Некорректно" – мне это ничего не говорит об ошибке, в другом браузере или найдите в это детальное описание ошибки

Comment: @nicaraguanec, читайте про CORS https://www.google.ru/search?q=CORS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Visman спасибо за отличную наводку! Только не совсем понятно, откуда здесь кроссдоменность: у меня же все ресурсы лежат на localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо [Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman) за наводку на CORS - действительно, при замене кода метода на:

```
function loadScript(scriptPath) {
$.ajax({
    url: scriptPath,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        console.log('Скрипт ' + scriptPath + ' загружен');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Скрипт ' + scriptPath + ' не загрузился');
    }
});
}
```

Все заработало как надо. IE, Chrome кушают такой "импорт" без нареканий.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы загружаете с другого домена и он принадлежит вам или есть доступ к серверу то вам поможет заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ([CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). Статья на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114432/)

В противном случае по политике безопасности вы не можете обратиться с помощью `JS` к этому домену.